# How to handle ON, TN, and S/N in quantlib

Tags: fixed-income, quantlib

I'm wondering how to precisely handle the quote convention of ON, TN, and S/N of FX quote. How to handle these convention in quantlib.

Here is my code, is that correct?

````
settlementDays = 2 #OIS convention
discount_term_structure = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()

oindex_on = ql.OvernightIndex('',0,ql.USDCurrency(),calendar,ois_dayCount,discount_term_structure)
oindex_tn = ql.OvernightIndex('',1,ql.USDCurrency(),calendar,ois_dayCount,discount_term_structure)
oindex_sn = ql.OvernightIndex('',2,ql.USDCurrency(),calendar,ois_dayCount,discount_term_structure)
oindex = ql.OvernightIndex('',settlementDays,ql.USDCurrency(),calendar,ois_dayCount,discount_term_structure)

oisHelpers = []
oisHelpers.append(ql.OISRateHelper(0,ql.Period(ois_data.loc[0,'Tenor']), ql.QuoteHandle(ois_data.loc[0,'Rate_handler']),oindex_on))
oisHelpers.append(ql.OISRateHelper(1,ql.Period(ois_data.loc[1,'Tenor']), ql.QuoteHandle(ois_data.loc[1,'Rate_handler']),oindex_tn))
oisHelpers.append(ql.OISRateHelper(2,ql.Period(ois_data.loc[2,'Tenor']), ql.QuoteHandle(ois_data.loc[2,'Rate_handler']),oindex_sn))

oisHelpers = oisHelpers + [ql.OISRateHelper(settlementDays,ql.Period(ois_data.loc[i,'Tenor']), ql.QuoteHandle(ois_data.loc[i,'Rate_handler'])\
                                            ,oindex) for i in range(3,len(ois_data))]```

Tenor   Rate    Rate_handler
0   1D  0.0160  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
1   1D  0.0159  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
2   1D  0.0159  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
3   1W  0.0159  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
4   2W  0.0159  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
5   3W  0.0159  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
6   1M  0.0159  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
7   2M  0.0158  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
8   3M  0.0157  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
9   6M  0.0151  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
10  9M  0.0145  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
11  1Y  0.0138  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
12  2Y  0.0122  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
13  3Y  0.0112  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
14  4Y  0.0114  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
15  5Y  0.0115  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
16  6Y  0.0116  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
17  7Y  0.0118  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
18  8Y  0.0121  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
19  9Y  0.0124  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
20  10Y 0.0127  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
21  12Y 0.0131  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
22  15Y 0.0137  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
23  20Y 0.0143  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
24  25Y 0.0145  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
25  30Y 0.0146  <QuantLib.QuantLib.SimpleQuote; proxy of <Swig...
````

Comment: I just change the tenor of ON, TN and S/N to 1D. Is that a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is the best way to implement it.

From a curve construction perspective the index for ON, SN and TN is the same and is just used to get the rate conventions.

```
index = ql.OvernightIndex('USD_ON', 0, ql.USDCurrency(), ql.UnitedStates(), ql.Actual360())
helpers = ql.RateHelperVector()
helpers.append( ql.OISRateHelper(0, ql.Period('1D'), ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.0010)), index) )
helpers.append( ql.OISRateHelper(1, ql.Period('1D'), ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.0015)), index) )
helpers.append( ql.OISRateHelper(2, ql.Period('1D'), ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.0020)), index) )

import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame([{
    "earliestDate": h.earliestDate().ISO(),
    "pillarDate": h.pillarDate().ISO(),
    "maturityDate": h.maturityDate().ISO(),
    "quote": h.quote().value()
} for h in helpers])
```

[image]

```
crv = ql.PiecewiseLogLinearDiscount(ql.Date().todaysDate(), helpers, ql.ActualActual())
crv.nodes()
```

((Date(12,6,2020), 1.0),
 (Date(15,6,2020), 0.9999916667361105),
 (Date(16,6,2020), 0.9999875001215266),
 (Date(17,6,2020), 0.9999819446662784))

Comment: Thanks! this make sense.

Comment: BTY, how to handle this on DepositRateHelper? What's the best way to set parameter

Comment: https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/thelpers.html

Comment: Just remember o/n and t/n dont always exist - if you are doing some general work then this is a headache you need to be aware of.